# S3Fox Exception: Too Many Arguments

Tags: firefox-extensions, amazon-s3

I'm running the S3Fox add-on in FireFox 38.0.1

Getting this error when I try to download a file from Amazon S3 to my local PC:

[Exception... "Not enough arguments [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI]"  nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://s3fox/content/js/xmlhttpNew.js :: s3_HttpClient.prototype.downloadFile :: line 729"  data: no]

Is there anything I can do to fix, or has the developer of this wonderful free utility just stopped supporting it?  I sent him a support email back in March 2015, no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS` is an exception caused by a change made in Firefox 36. (I cannot find any information on this specific change except the fact that people have had this problem since the latest update.)

The developer has stopped working on this and is thus unable to fix the issue, so you will have to move on to another tool.

Comment: Thanks, never knew for 100% it was a global issue.  Too bad he didn't open source the project.  Trying DragonDrive and looking at TNTDrive next.